# Basic authentication in Lumen

Tags: authentication, lumen

I have already written an API call for check authentication using Laravel. I need to move that controller to Lumen for use it as micro service.

This is my controller in Laravel.

```
public function byCredantial(Request $request)
{
    $user = [
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password')
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
        $response = $this->getSuccess(Auth::user()->id);

        return response()->json($response, 200);
    } else {
        $response = $this->getError($user);

        return response()->json($response, 401);
    }
}
```

Lumen doc is not provide how to do such authentication. They has not function for check creadential is correct. How can i do this in Lumen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Lumen. Facades are disabled by default (if you want to enable it you can see the instructions in the [documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)), but I would not recommend enabling the facades as the add additional overhead to your application. Instead, I would modify your function to call `app('auth')`. This will return the class that the `Auth` facade proxies without loading all the other facades.

```
public function byCredantial(Request $request)
{
    $user = [
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password')
    ];

    $auth = app('auth');

    if ($auth->attempt($user)) {
        $response = $this->getSuccess($auth->user()->id);

        return response()->json($response, 200);
    } else {
        $response = $this->getError($user);

        return response()->json($response, 401);
    }
}
```

Also, I would recommend reading the authentication [documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) and placing the bulk of this code in the `AuthServiceProvider`.